# Difference between SparseArray and Hashmap?

Tags: android, hashmap, sparse-matrix

i want to know performance and efficency between `SparseArray` and `HashMap` and which one is better to use. i can't undestand when to use `SparseArray` and when `Hashmap`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SparseArray` is the choice you should make when your map key is an integer, and those integers are not sequential, meaning not 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... n - but more like, 43, 2045, 12, 5.

Now, let's assume for a moment that your keys were integers, but also sequential (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... n). What would be the best choice of collection in this case? Well, lets assume that your values are `Strings`. In this case, your best choice here would be a `String` array (`String[]`). The reason for this is that the `String` array answers all your needs with a minimum impact on performance.

`myStringArray[0]` would return the `String` value of the key '0', and so on.

`SparseArray` works exactly like this, except we allow some values inside the array to be empty (hence, 'sparse'). A `SparseArray` will create a large array behind the scenes, and use the integer keys as the indexes of the array where the values are placed.

Essentially, `HashMaps` also work this way - behind the scenes there is a large integer array which is used to place values. The only difference is that in `HashMaps`, the keys are not integers, they could be anything. For sake of our example, lets say the keys are `Strings`. What a `HashMap` will do is it will use a hash function to convert this `String` key into an integer, then use that to position the value in the array. This can lead to cases where two different `Strings` produce the same integers. In these cases, the `HashMap` will perform another operation such as queueing values in the array, or producing a new key, and so on. This, and the production of an integer key via a hash function, can sometimes involve quite a bit of performance.

`SparseArray` allows you to skip this entirely since with integer keys, none of this is necessary, and therefore is more efficient.

Comment: Very nice explanation.

Comment: If https://developer.android.com doesn't lie you should use HashMaps if you have "data structures that may contain large numbers of items" because SparseArrays "are not intended to be appropriate" for that case.

Answer (score 2):

Android documentation for a SparseArray says

1. It is generally slower than a traditional HashMap, since lookups 
   require a binary search and adds and removes require inserting and
   deleting entries in the array.
2. It is intended to be more memory 
       efficient than using a HashMap to map Integers to Objects, both
       because it avoids auto-boxing keys and its data structure doesn't
       rely on an extra entry object for each mapping.

So, in short ; Sparse arrays can be used to replace hash maps when the key is a primitive type.

Comment: Your conclusion seems to be wrong. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html : "The implementation is not intended to be appropriate for data structures that may contain large numbers of items. It is generally slower than a traditional HashMap, since lookups require a binary search and adds and removes require inserting and deleting entries in the array. For containers holding up to hundreds of items, the performance difference is not significant, less than 50%."